# CSS hr tag in a nav bar with a margin

Tags: css, html

How do I add a rule above and below my nav bar? I tried an HR tag, but that seemed to make a lot of space around the nav bar. Here is my html and here is the example of how I want to do it.

http://matthewtbrown.com/jeffandcricketquilt/

http://matthewtbrown.com/jeffandcricketquilt/rule.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to change your html at all, you can add this to your css

```
nav ul:before {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    bottom: 5px;
    content: "";
    left: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    z-index:0;
}
nav ul {
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color:#000;
}
nav ul li{
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}
```

and remove the background-color from the `li` elements (*since i added it to the `ul`*)

Answer (score 0):

Try applying this CSS to the nav bar:

```
border-top: 1px solid #eee
border-bottom: 1px solid #eee
```

Comment: I was asking this question and found that someone had asked it here. This answer is by far the simplest and gets my vote.

Answer (score 0):

Use borders and padding:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
    text-align: center;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: .2em;
}

ul {
    padding: .5em;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}



nav li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0 2em;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bfqLj/)

Answer (score 0):

I would apply an outline to the ul tag, so the css should be:

```
nav ul{
  outline-color: white;
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-offset: -7px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 848px;
}
```

Comment: Outline should not be used as static styling of elements. It is meant to be used as visual markers for elements to stand out. :focus uses it to show e.g. where in a form you are and keyboard users use it to navigate web pages. The border property is a lot more fitting for static styling.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to add a padding to the nav element, 4px makes good with width of li elements. Also add float: left

Now add border-top and border-bottom to the ul element. Add float: left here as well. This will switch your li element around as they have a fixed width. lower the width of them to 210px and things should be fine.

CSS additions to your code:

```
nav {
  padding: 4px
  float: left;
}

nav ul {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  float: left;
}

nav li {
  width: 210px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `line-height` is the same as `font-size` you can manipulate border distance by changing `padding-bottom` of list element, here is my example:

```
.headerSection ul.navigation li  a {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    text-decoration: none ;
    padding-bottom: 10px; 
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
} 

.headerSection ul.navigation li a:hover {
    border-bottom-color: #e8bf5d;
}
```